# Efficient way to check for inequality

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a trigger that is doing

```
IF (@A <> @B)
    ...
```

but this will not work for NULL values on either @A or @B. The way it's normally done is

```
IF (@A <> @B) OR (@A IS NOT NULL AND @B IS NULL) OR (@A IS NULL AND @B IS NOT NULL)
```

but this involves up to 9 comparisons versus 1!

I could do

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

but apparently this is not recommended (and to be deprecated).

So what is the best solution for this? Just take 9 comparisons for a simple inequality check when it should be 1? The trigger is not performance critical, but it does need to be fast. When batch loading, this could slow it down considerably.

**PEFORMANCE TESTS**

Here are the results of a [performance test](http://pastebin.com/rwtWVfqV) that checks for inequality a million times such that 90% of the time the values are not equal, 10% of the time each value may be null.

```
IF (@A <> @B) OR (@A IS NULL AND @B IS NOT NULL) OR (@A IS NOT NULL AND @B IS NULL)
```

Result: average 3848ms

```
IF (ISNULL(@A, 0) <> ISNULL(@B, 0))
```

Result: average 3942ms

```
IF (@A = @B) GOTO Equal ELSE IF @A IS NULL AND @B IS NULL GOTO Equal
```

Result: average 4140ms

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT @A EXCEPT SELECT @B)
```

Result: average 7795ms

The times don't really matter, it's the relative difference that counts. Clearly, the **classic approach is the fastest**. Likely MSSQL has internally optimised for this type of check.

Test run on MacBook Pro (Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4Ghz, 8GB RAM inside a Vista VM running MSSQL 2008 Express).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the results of a [performance test](http://pastebin.com/rwtWVfqV) that checks for inequality a million times such that 90% of the time the values are not equal, 10% of the time each value may be null.

```
IF (@A <> @B) OR (@A IS NULL AND @B IS NOT NULL) OR (@A IS NOT NULL AND @B IS NULL)
```

Result: average 3848ms

```
IF (ISNULL(@A, 0) <> ISNULL(@B, 0))
```

Result: average 3942ms

```
IF (@A = @B) GOTO Equal ELSE IF @A IS NULL AND @B IS NULL GOTO Equal
```

Result: average 4140ms

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT @A EXCEPT SELECT @B)
```

Result: average 7795ms

The times don't really matter, it's the relative difference that counts. Clearly, the **classic approach is the fastest**. Likely MSSQL has internally optimised for this type of check.

Test run on MacBook Pro (Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4Ghz, 8GB RAM inside a Vista VM running MSSQL 2008 Express).

Answer (score 7):

ANSI SQL has `IS DISTINCT FROM` but this is not implemented in SQL Server. It can be [simulated](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) in a way that doesn't rely on magic constants and is sargable if used on columns

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT @A EXCEPT SELECT @B)
     PRINT 'Different'
```

Comment: very nice - I assume this avoids the possibility of a collision; e.g. defaulting the value to a valid data value or of 2 NULLs being defaulted to the same value.

Comment: @Karl - Yes it doesn't rely on there being some sentinel value that can't occur in the data.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld - Unlike the other two answers it is correct for all possible variable values. It will be plenty fast enough. This comparison is something pointless spending any time optimising. It will never be a significant factor.

Comment: @MartinSmith: even if you have that statement run 20 times per record per update per table?

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld - Yes. Compared to the cost of the update itself (locating the row, doing the update, logging it) it will be insignificant. You haven't shown your query but it is entirely possible SQL Server won't evaluate it 20 times per row anyway. And you could just cache the result in a bit variable up front anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith See my response below.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Whilst your solution looks nice, I suspect it adds to the overall number of instructions necessary to compute inequality. Depending on implementation of the DBMS, your query would likely result in creating an in-memory set, applying a set operation (except) and checking for set element count. This is probably much more than 9 comparisons.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld - Instead of guessing how it may be implemented internally you should focus on optimizing proven bottlenecks. This won't be.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is the best way to check for nullability and provide default value.

```
IF ( ISNULL(@A, 0) <> ISNULL(@B, 0) )
```

General Syntax

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

> The value of check_expression is returned if it is not NULL;
>   otherwise, replacement_value is returned after it is implicitly
>   converted to the type of check_expression, if the types are different.
>   replacement_value can be truncated if replacement_value is longer than
>   check_expression.

Refer: [MSDN - ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Comment: What if `0` is a legitimate value? If `@A` is `0` and `@B` is NULL it will report they are the same.

Comment: Maybe by a fraction. But it is more readable and that's what it's all about.

Comment: I have supposed that @A and @B are `Int` datatype so I have put default value `0`

Comment: Readability is nice, in this situation, performance is more important. I'm checking for inequality average 20 times per record. Most of the time it's not going to match so every "check" results in 9 comparisons. That's already 180 comparisons per row. This trigger runs on every update for all tables. The DB is batch loaded on occassion. Performance matters.

Comment: In addition to 0 being a valid number, what is both values are NULL, (which should still not match but will in this example)

Comment: @HarshBaid: @A and @B are sql_variant

Comment: This is probably the nicest solution for readability's with virtually 0 overhead. However, it's not ANSI and it needs a suitably chosen replacement value (which isn't always available). Unfortunately, it's not accepted as the answer since I was after performance and looks like standard approach is fastest. Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 2):

you can do following

`ISNULL(@A,'N') <> ISNULL(@B,'N')`

Answer (score 0):

I know many won't like this, but as performance is an **important** issue I'm using this (unless someone shows a good reason)

```
IF @A = @B GOTO Equal ELSE IF @A IS NULL AND @B IS NULL GOTO Equal
NotEqual:
  PRINT 'Different'
Equal:
```

This is much faster as almost always @A and @B are equal resulting in only 1 comparison. In the minority of cases when @A and @B are not equal, an average of 1.5 further comparisons are required to determine non-equality.

This is for column-level auditing of row updates within a trigger. The comparisons @A and @B denote "old value" and "new value" for every column in every row in every update for every table.

Comment: @MartinSmith OP has got benchmark [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15489955/468718) as of now..